# Is there ENS Support for Gnosis?

Tags: gnosis-safe

Does Gnosis Safe support ENS? Can a multi-sig owner be an ENS that can potentially change its resolved address, and thus, the owner privilege changes?

Answer (score 1):

Safe owners can only be Ethereum addresses.
Check the type of `owner` in `addOwnerWithThreshold` for reference: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/base/OwnerManager.sol#L51